# Copying Content from a file to another when a new line is added using poweshell script

Tags: powershell, log-files, shell-scripting

I have a file named server1.txt and one more file named server1_copy.txt. In server1.txt, all logs will be added from the application. So whenever a new line is added in the server1.txt, we need to copy that and paste it in the server1_copy.txt. We can keep the code in powershell script and schedule it to run every 30 minutes to perform this action.

I dont have much experiance in Powershell script. But I gone through so many documents in online, could not find a right solution to this.

Does anyone have any idea how we can achieve this using Powershell scripts.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the whole file?

Comment: What kind of code do you have in your PowerShell script which would perform this action every 30 minutes? I am confused about at what stage in this process you are at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will copy new lines added to server1.txt to server1_copy.txt in real time.

```
 Get-Content -Path 'server1.txt' -Tail 0 -Wait | ForEach-Object { Add-Content -Value $_ -Path 'server1_copy.txt' }
```

If you need to bring the files in sync before running the above or that real time is simply unnecessary, a file copy can be done with the `Copy-Item` cmdlet

```
Copy-Item -Path 'server1.txt' -Destination 'server1_copy.txt'
```

Comment: This will also copy already existing lines again and again.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider You are wrong, it will only copy new lines.

Comment: Only until it is started again.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider You are wrong, no lines are copied at start

Comment: In that case It misses lines that have been added between runs. One way or another, it doesn't guarantee that everything is copied.